# get domain name only in not full path

Tags: php, parsing

I know I can parse full url with parse_url in php, but my problem is when I have not full url ormat, how can I get domain name.

my urls are in 2 condtion sometimes in full path and sometimes in not full path,

as example
 `blahblah.com/ddddd/fffff/a.php?ddddd`
 `http://blahblah.com/ddddd/fffff/a.php?ddddd`

I want it return me **blahbla.com**

my url is not browser url,treat them like a variable not current url

Comment: parse_url works just fine to get the host even if the protocol is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tricky way :)

```
 $url_p=  parse_url($url);

    if(!isset($url_p['scheme'])){
        $url='http://'.$url;
        $url_p=parse_url($url);
    }
echo $url_p['host'];
```

Answer (score 1):

The right way to achieve this is by making use of `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];`

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
```

Answer (score 1):

use

```
echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
```

or to remove 'www.' use

```
echo str_replace('www.', '', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$url='blahblah.com/ddddd/fffff/a.php?ddddd';
$Urls = parse_url($url);        
if(!isset($Urls['host'])){          
   $url = 'http://'.$url;
   $Urls = parse_url($url);
}       
echo $Urls['host'];
```

Comment: Updated answer. Check!

Answer (score 0):

The best and official way to do it would be using `parse_url()`
But in your particular case you need a trick:

```
$url = 'http://'.preg_replace('!^https?://!i', '', $url);
```

1. First, you intentionally make sure there's no http:// or https:// at the beginning.
2. THEN you add your own http:// at the beginning
3. And NOW this $url is finally eligible for parse_url():

`echo parse_url( $url, PHP_URL_HOST );`

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
    $uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; // $uri == example.com/index
    $exploded_uri = explode('/', $uri); //$exploded_uri ==     array('example.com','index')
    $domain_name = $exploded_uri[0]; //$domain_name = 'example.com'
```

Comment: Please avoid providing block quote answers, you should explain what your code does and how it resolves the issue.